# Why exit animation not working in framer-motion?

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion

so i have some article that should have exit animation, but it doesn't have one

i tried using this without AnimatePresence, but it also dont work

```
"use client";

import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

const PageWrapper = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode="wait" initial={true}>
      {children}
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default PageWrapper;
```

```
"use client";

import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

const variants: any = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0, x: 0, y: 20 },
  enter: { opacity: 1, x: 0, y: 0 },
  exit: { opacity: 0, x: -0, y: 20 },
};

const Article = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ y: 20, opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ y: 0, opacity: 1 }}
      exit={{ y: 20, opacity: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.4 }}
    >
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default Article;
```

where is error? how i can fix it?